# pages.isfan data fetch error

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I use c# SDK to fetch pages.isfan data , but it always error.

```
var args=new Dictionary<string,object>();
                args["uid"] = fb_uid;
                args["page_id"] = _isfan_page_id;
                var isfanobj = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Api("pages.isfan", args);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in isfanobj)
                {
                    Response.Write(
                        string.Format("key:{0}\nvalue:{1}\n",
                                      entry.Key,entry.Value                                          
                                     )
                    );
                }
```

pages.isfan need 2 parameters: page_id and uid

loop iterate my "isfanobj" , a dictionary type, the "key" always be "error".

Is my code any wrong?

If wrong, how do I get pages.isfan data?

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I only want to know how to fetch pages.isfan data only use C# SDK, without Javascript SDK.

Anyone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what I user and it works great for me.

```
 Dictionary<string, object> parms = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                parms.Add( "method", "pages.isFan" );
                parms.Add( "page_id", YourAppId );
                parms.Add( "uid", UsersFbId );

                var isFan = fb.Api( parms );
                if( (bool)isFan )
                {
                  //this user is a fan
                }
```

I find the fb.Api signature that you pass in all the parameters as a Dictionary works best for me.

I just wanted to add that when dealing with the REST API it is not the same as dealing with the Graph API you have to pass in the method as a parameter.

Also once the Rest API is fully deprecated we will all have to switch to the new method... If they ever come out with it.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! I had used another method to resolve it. Use XMLDocument to load http//api.facebook.com/method/pages.isfan?page_id=xxxxx&uid=xxxxx&access_token=xxxxxxx and fetch pages_isFan_response node's value. But your api call is right method to use SDK, thanks!

Comment: The way I look at it is there is no wrong way as long as the end results are the same.